# Перестали загружаться метки на карту из XML

Tags: xml, yandex-maps-api

Буквально недавно все работало.
Количество запросов, судя по статистике не превышено.
Сайт сейчас работает на HTTP, на бесплатном хостинге.
Думал может дело в то, что требуется HTTPS - пробую перевести его через Cloudflare.
При загрузке в Chrome вижу вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и вот это:
[image: Картинка]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT - это, скорее всего какое-то расширение браузера хулиганит.

Comment: Если вопрос с geoXML, пишите лучше сразу в поддержку Яндекса. Эти файлы для загрузки на карту обрабатываются на их стороне, потому могут быть вопросы доступа их сервера на ваш сайт или у них что на серверной стороне поломалось.

Comment: Интересуют последние три предупреждения.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю где у них поддержка. Раньше хотя бы клуб был. Сейчас ссылка сюда. Но ответов не то чтобы много.

Comment: API Яндекс Карт поддерживают только по почте. Пишите на мыло maps-api@support.yandex.ru

Comment: Или можете оформить вопрос в их ФОС: https://forms.yandex.ru/surveys/5997